# nginx escaping (+) sign in rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to redirect some hits based on the image name in my Nginx configuration.

This is how it looks now:

```
        location / {

                rewrite ^/static-v3/(.*)/creditcard_sslseals_public.png https://somenewurl.com/credit-card-seals.png permanent;
                rewrite ^/static-v3/(.*)/creditcard+sslseals_public.png https://somenewurl.com/credit-card-seals.png permanent;

                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

So the first condition with the filename `creditcard_sslseals_public.png` works properly, but the second is not working since there is a `+` sign in the image name like `creditcard+sslseals_public.png`, so I am getting a 404.

How can I escape the + in the second condition, but keep the regex before `^/static-v3/(.*)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` has a special meaning in a regular expression and needs to be escaped.

One option is to use a backslash to escape the character:

```
^/static-v3/(.*)/creditcard\+sslseals_public.png
```

Alternatively, create a character class containing just one character:

```
^/static-v3/(.*)/creditcard[+]sslseals_public.png
```